# Error on App Initialization: mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h`

Tags: ruby, bundler, ruby-on-rails-5

The error occurs when initializing the app (either through `rails s` or a `rake` command). So far I've only seen this error for other people on a `bundle` or `gem install`.

The only thing we might be doing differently is bundling on a different server and then gziping vendor, .bundle, and Gemfile.lock. The server we bundle install on has `ruby-dev` (the usual solution to the above error).

This strategy worked with Rails 4.2, but now on Rails 5 (with a variety of gems updated) it requires `ruby-dev` on both the prep box and the prod boxes.

The main question here: Why is `ruby-dev` needed to initialize the app?